# Is there an excel formula that can check the number of words in consecutive cells and give an output based on conditions?

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am trying to create an output in excel based off the number of words in cells. Essentially i want to check if the sum of the words in 3 cells is = 1,2 or >=3. Im using the len formula which i have successfully used on single cell conditions but im struggling to create the formula that would check multiple cells.

```
Below is an example of my data:

    Column A        Column B       Column C
    Cat;dog                         Bird
```

Formula

```
=SUMIF(AND(LEN(TRIM(A4))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B4," ",""))+1, LEN(TRIM(C4))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C4," ",""))+1, >=3), "Titanium")
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W6nFr-W0r-XWZnvrFWndsvdBEEGHMQUa/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=103068518904190156690&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Are your words separated by blanks, commas or semicolon?

Comment: I've updated your file with the corrected formula so you can compare yours and the one that works. Also, please, check updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

First I made a single formula to work on a single cell. It ignores semicolons and commas to calculate total words. That formula is in column F and it's:

```
=IF(LEN(E5)=0;0;LEN(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(E5;";";" ");",";" ")))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(E5;";";" ");",";" "));" ";""))+1
```

Notice I added an IF to make sure that blank cells will count as 0 words (because the +1 will be added wrongly and we need to avoid this.

Now you just need to sum up all results and we get 8 words.

What you want is to get this result with a single formula and that can be perfomed with array formulas. In cell F11 my formula is:

```
=SUM(IF(LEN(E5:E8)=0;0;LEN(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(E5:E8;";";" ");",";" ")))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(E5:E8;";";" ");",";" "));" ";""))+1))
```

You need to introduce this formula pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> or it won't work!

Now you got the result in a single formula and you just need to add your conditions mentioned in your post

**UPDATE:** In your Google Sheets, the correct formula would be:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(SUM(IF(LEN(TRIM(A3:B3))=0,0,LEN(TRIM(A3:C3))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3:C3," ",""))+1))>=3,"Good","Bad"))
```

Please, notice Excel **is not** the same as Google Sheets so sometimes the formulas may be different in one of them.

Comment: Thank you for this great advise and reply -- quick question on introducting the array...what action do I have to take in order to introduce it ? click on the cell and press CTRL+ENTER+SHIFT ?

Comment: And just another question just to save you having to reply twice -- can i introduce a condition outcome at the end i.e if the outcome is >3 then output "Good" for example

Comment: Yes to both. Just make the formula as you would do it normally and instead of confirming with enter, press CTRL+ENTER+SHIFT. If it worked, you will see `{` and `}` in your formula bar. Check [Excel array formulas, functions and constants - examples and guidelines](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/02/25/array-formulas-functions-excel/)

Comment: Thank you -- when i confirm the formula i get the "Theres a problem with this formula error"... if copied and pasted the formula so syntax should be fine

Comment: My Excel setup requieres `;` as argument separator in formulas. If yours is comma, you need to replace all of them

Comment: =SUM(IF(LEN(TRIM(AB4:AD4))=0,0,LEN(TRIM(AB4:AD4))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(AB4:AD4," ",""))+1>3),"Good")

Comment: The above formula has worked for me when i confirm the array -- iv added the condition good but im getting "#VALUE" as the outcome ? any idea why this might be the case

Comment: The `SUM` part should be inside and IF. Something like `IF(SUM(long_array_formula)>3, "Good","Bad")`

Comment: Thank you so much ---- So close now its nearly there haha ---  the below formula should show "Good" as the result is 4 but its actually showing it as "Bad" i.e false

=IF(SUM(LEN(TRIM(AB4:AD4))=0,0,LEN(TRIM(AB4:AD4))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(AB4:AD4," ",""))+1>=3),"Good","Bad")

Comment: Try `=IF(SUM(LEN(TRIM(AB4:AD4))=0,0,LEN(TRIM(AB4:AD4))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(AB4:AD4," ",""))+1)>=3,"Good","Bad")` and remember pressing CTRL+ENTER+SHIFT. If it does not work, please, sahre a copy of your file so we can adjust it

Comment: No problem it seems to be only displaying good now --- trying to find where i can share/upload the file here cant seem to find the icon ?

Comment: @RyanDennehy You need to upload somewhere like Google Drive and edit your original post and add the link. There is no defualt share option in Stack Overflow

Comment: Apologies thought there was that option -- iv shared the link to the file now